# C# GetActiveTcpConnections() about only one app

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

Hello everyone i have a c# program that print all my tcp connections, but is possible print only tcp connections that a specific app use? This is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Active TCP Connections");
            IPGlobalProperties properties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
            TcpConnectionInformation[] connections = properties.GetActiveTcpConnections();
            foreach (TcpConnectionInformation c in connections)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} <==> {1}",
                                  c.LocalEndPoint.ToString(),
                                  c.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: The MAC address of an ARP contains the manufacture, model, and serial number.  You can see the ARP table from cmd.exe >ARP -A  The MAC is a physical address.

Comment: Sorry man I don't understand

Comment: Are you connect to a device or just to a server.  Every Ethernet Interface has a MAC Address the is returning in an ARP message.  So not sure if you were referring to a device or just an application.  An Application would have a port number and then you would need to filter only on certain ports.

Comment: I'm referring an app, a game that allow me to connect a server. Often use the port number 30120. I only need that my script print in console only the tcp connections that use my game

Comment: Try : foreach (TcpConnectionInformation c in connections.Where(x => x.RemoteEndPoint .Port ==  30120))

Comment: No man, because not ever the servers use 30120 port. I need of that control all tcp connections only for the game.

Comment: Then what port number is used?

Comment: Depend of server man, the script need to find which port use with the game process.

Comment: You only have two choices 1) Search by Port number 2) Search by MAC if game process has a MAC that is can be associated with the game process.  Like if you have a XBOX the game server will have Microsoft and the manufacturer and XBOX as the Model.